# Parsing dom error in java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, apache-poi

I am trying to parse an XML and then insert it an Excel File.
If I run my code it works even with errors but I cannot make any modification to it because I still got errors. Here is my code:

```
public class Parsing {
    private void parseXmlFile(){
        //get the factory
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {
        //using Factory get an instance of document builder
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        //parse using builder to get DOM representation 
        dom = db.parse("Employee.xml"); }
    } catch )

    }
  }
```

What is wrong with this? 
Can someone help me? I've been searching all over google and it's eating my nerves.

Comment: The code you posted won't compile, please check it.

Comment: you forgot to type - catch(Exception e){} Exception - something more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be like this :-

```
private void parseXmlFile(){
        //get the factory
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {
        //using Factory get an instance of document builder
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        //parse using builder to get DOM representation 
       Document  dom = db.parse("Employee.xml"); 
    } catch(IOException ex ){ // OR Any Specific Exception should be catched here
// your error handling code here
}

    }
```

Also `Employee.xml` should be in the current directory or give complete abosulte path of `Employee.xml` file also.

Comment: You can handle some `{` and `}` in your *IDE* also, check the above code once again, edited that

Comment: Done, thank you Ankit :) . I am having one more problem with the dom variable(dom cannot be resolved to a variable). Do I need to import same library ??

Comment: @user3619789 Glad that it helped.yes you need to add `Document` class also. use the above edited code & use keys (ctrl+shift+O) if you are using Eclipse IDE to import all the necessary classes

Comment: @user3619789 if it worked for you, you can mark an upvote for it so that others can also make use of it :)